# Adding View to a Custom ViewGroup

Tags: android

I am trying to add Views to a custom ViewGroup.  The ViewGroup gets drawn, but no Views that were added to it are visible.  LineView's (which extends a View) onDraw() method does not get called.  What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.main);

         ShapeView shapeView = new ShapeView(this);
         shapeView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
         drawContainer = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.draw_container);
         drawContainer.addView(shapeView);   
    }
 }


 public class ShapeView extends ViewGroup {

     private LineView mLineView;

     public ShapeView (Context context) {
         super(context);
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams p = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
         this.setLayoutParams(p); 
         mLineView = new LineView(context);
         this.addView(mLineView);   
     }     
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe wrong but should you not be adding the shapeView to your layout "main"? What is drawContainer? I can't see it being instantiated and not  in the docs. I assume main contains a relative/linear layout.

Access it by:

```
RelativeLayout rel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
```

(where the id is changed to match your id)

then:

```
rel.addView(shapeView);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to paste that line of code to the question.  Updated.

Comment: nah it is ok,  I thought it was 50/50. Ok so what do you actually see? Do you get a red square? or do you see nothing?

Comment: I see the red square and nothing else.  I have a feeling I should be putting something into my onLayout() method, but I'm not sure what it's used for and how to code it properly.

Comment: I cannot see LineView in the documentation either. Is this another class you have? If so might be worth adding it.

Comment: It worked once I implemented the onLayout() method of the ViewGroup :)